# How to make a python script which can logoff, shutdown, and restart a computer?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

**Background**

I am currently in the process of teaching myself python, and I thought that it would be a very cool project to have a sort of "control center" in which I could shutdown, restart, and log off of my computer. I also want to use the subprocess module, as I have heard that the import OS module is outdated.

**Current Code**

```
def shutdown(self):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-f", "-s", "-t", "60"])
```

**Question**

What I am really asking is, is there a way (using the subprocess module) to logoff of and restart my computer?

**Tech Specs**

Python 2.7.3

Windows 7, 32 bit

Comment: -r perhaps to restart?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried it and the issue is - the computer cannot find the file "restart", the options (-f, -s, -t) don't really matter in that respect.

Comment: I think the switches should be `/f`, `/s`, etc.

Comment: Why does it have to be with a slash, not a minus? It has worked fine so far - is it against good coding practices? Lastly, what do you mean by switches? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: If I remember correctly, Windows uses `/f` instead of `-f` (just as an example). I may be wrong.

Comment: @Blender: As of Windows NT 3.1, most tools allow either. (And even before that, DOS and Windows had a secret flag you could set to allow that.) But it's still generally not documented. (Probably not because they're afraid IBM will cancel the contract for PC-DOS, which was the original reason, so much as because they're trying to avoid confusing people with too many options…)

Comment: By the way, you're right to use `subprocess`, but the `os` module is _not_ outdated. It's just the `os.system` and `os.popen` (and related) functions within.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To restart:

```
shutdown /r
```

To log off:

```
shutdown /l
```

The final code block (as requested):

Log off:

```
def shutdown(self):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-f", "-s", "-t", "60"])
```

Restart:

```
def shutdown(self):
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["shutdown", "-f", "-r", "-t", "60"])
```

Comment: How can I  force logging off?. What if the OS ask you to save your files first? Then you are stuck. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

First you have to:

```
import subprocess
```

To shutdown your Windows PC:

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

To restart your windows PC

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/r"])
```

To logout your Windows PC:

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/l "])
```

To shutdown your Windows PC after 900s:

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s", "/t", "900"])
```

To abort shutting down because there is no good reason to shutdown your pc with a python script, you were just copy-pasting code from stackoverflow:

```
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/a "])
```

I only tried these function calls in Python 3.5. First of all, I do not think this has changed since python 2.7, and second: it is 2016, so I guess you have made the switch already since asking this question.

Comment: The 900s shutdown delay call is wrong.  The `/t` flag is used for adjusting the timeout, not `/s`.  Further, I think you're intending `/s` to be used for shutdown as above. I wouldn't expect anything good to happen combining both `/r` and `/s`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get `shutdown` to work somehow, you can always just call the function it calls out of the USER library. You *could* do this via `ctypes` or `win32api`, but you can also just do this:

```
subprocess.call(['rundll32', 'user.exe,ExitWindowsExec')
```

Or you could call the higher-level shell function that the start menu uses:

```
subprocess.call(['rundll32', 'shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 2')
```

(See MSDN documentation on these functions.)

I think this is probably the worst way to do it. If you want to run a command, run `shutdown`; if you want to use the API, use `win32api`. But if you've got a bizarrely screwed-up system where `shutdown /r` just doesn't work, it's an option.