# How to do if else statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am a python/scrapy newbie. I am trying to scrape a website for practice and basically when **data-src** exists, then I want to use the value from **img::attr(data-src),**

```
def parse(self, response):

  for item in items:

    listing['img'] =  item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract()
```

otherwise if data-src does not exist then use **img::attr(src)**

```
listing['img'] =  item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

But the question is how to do it in  an if statement?

```
listing['img'] =  if item.css('div img::attr(data-src)'): item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract() else: item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

Of course this does not work and it has an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for your help and input!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functions and if - else in python. Codeacademy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149667/functions-and-if-else-in-python-codeacademy)

Comment: @BoltClock♦ you are right, it really should be about the best way of using multiple css selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
for item in items:
    if item.css('div img::attr(data-src)'): 
        listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract() 

    else:
        listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks for you quick response, @avstenit

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), here is its syntax:

```
a = "thing" if test else "other_thing"
```

So in your case it makes:

```
listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract() if item.css('div img::attr(data-src)') else item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

If you want an [if else condition](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements), here is how you do it:

```
if test1:
  # your stuff
elif test2:
  # your other stuff
```

So in your case it makes

```
if item.css('div img::attr(data-src)'):
  listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract()
else:
  listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

It is more readable in this case in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Inline if/else in Python:

```
result = "X was 2" if x == 2 else "X wasn't 2"
```

Much more readable though in most cases to say:

```
if x == 2:
    # Do something
else:
    # Do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong position for `if`. It works as below:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 3 if x==2 else 4
>>> y
3
>>>
```

So you must change that line to:

```
>>> listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract() if item.css('div img::attr(data-src)') else item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could do the following:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for item in items:

        if item.css('div img::attr(data-src)'):

            listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(data-src)').extract() 

        else: 

            listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

Important: note the indentation which is compulsory in Python.

Answer (score 1):

for making your code short you can use multiple css selectors using or condition `,`

```
div img::attr(data-src), div img::attr(src)
```

so it should work for you as well which is very short then `if else` code

```
listing['img'] = item.css('div img::attr(data-src), div img::attr(src)').extract()
```

Comment: Tried, but somehow this does not work (has same results) as if else.

Comment: @WillW can you share the url with me ?