# Use python to shut down instance script runs on

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am running machine learning scripts that take a long time to finish. I want to run them on AWS on a faster processor and stop the instance when it finishes.

Can [boto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto/) be used within the running script to stop its own instance? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can use boto, here is the documentation for EC2 management 
http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html.

Comment: Yes. Boto can be used. Boto3 is better. When do you mean by `close down`? stop or terminate?

Comment: Stop. So it can even close down the instance that is running the boto script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Creating a Connection](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ec2_tut.html) on how to create a connection. Never tried this one before, so use caution. Also make sure the instance is EBS backed. Otherwise the instance will be terminated when you stop it.

```
import boto.ec2
import boto.utils

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1") # or your region

# Get the current instance's id
my_id = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['instance-id']

conn.stop_instances(instance_ids=[my_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

If your EC2 instance is running Linux, you can simply issue a `halt` or `shutdown` command to stop your EC2 instance. This allows you to shutdown your EC2 instance without requiring IAM permissions.

Comment: Take a look here on executing a shell command from Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764126/how-to-make-a-python-script-which-can-logoff-shutdown-and-restart-a-computer

Comment: `import subprocess` followed by `subprocess.call(["halt"])`.

Comment: @shahar_m did you try this out? It looks a little less elegant but a lot simpler.